# Join tables in ClickHouse with between condition

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I found out join in ClickHouse supports only equal expressions.
But I need to join two big tables with 'between' condition in ClickHouse.

How to implement this logic?

```
select a.*, b.name
from a
join b
  on a.id = b.id
  and a.start_dt between b.start_dt and b.end_dt;
```

got error

> *Code: 403, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Invalid expression for JOIN ON. Expected equals expression...*

Comment: Try a WHERE clause for the between condition. Or do ">= and <=" instead of between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
select a.*, b_name
from (
  select a.*, b.name AS b_name, b.start_dt AS b_start_dt, b.end_dt AS b_end_dt
  from a join b using id
  where a.start_dt between b_start_dt and b_end_dt
  )
```

Look at some JOIN specifics in [Clickhouse join with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64597112/303298).